# Remove unnecessary URL parts/parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a blog with article-urls like this `http://ali.dj/blog/unlimited-fps-in-unity-editor`

My old blog had URLs like this: `http://ali.dj/blog/unlimited-fps-in-unity-editor/comment-page1` etc.

When the article is valid but everything following it is unnecessary I would like to strip out parts and parameters after the URL.

This `http://ali.dj/blog/unlimited-fps-in-unity-editor/comment-page1`

or this `http://ali.dj/blog/unlimited-fps-in-unity-editor/comment-page1?ref=foo`

becomes this `http://ali.dj/blog/unlimited-fps-in-unity-editor`

Currently I've got a catch-all route which will redirect the user to the error-page

**How can I strip out unnecessary parts?**

Here's the `router.js` I currently use for articles:

```
this.route('blog', { 'path' : 'blog/'}, function() {

  this.route('post', { 'path' : ':permalink' })
  this.route('not-found', { 'path' : 'not-found'})
});

// Error routes
this.route('not-found', { path : '/not-found'})
this.route('catch-all', { path : '/*path'})  // redirects to not-found
```